# When processing multi line content in a powershell in Windows, why does it take every line and add it to your command history?

Tags: powershell

I started using `pwsh` in Linux, and it's a joy to use.  However, back on Windows it still sucks to use `powershell.exe` manly because when you paste text into a powershell window, it makes every single line of pasted code a single entry of command history!

In `pwsh` it makes everything you pasted becomes one entry in the command history...

How could Microsoft take better care of Linux users than Windows users, or is this some strange security thing?  What is the reason for this?

Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Windows Server 2016

Comment: This is question doesn't belong here, move it somewhere else.

Comment: `PSReadline` can work in both.

Answer (score 0):

This is not always the case. If you want this effect, there are ways to manufacture it:

```
PS H:\> $str = "this is line 1
>> this is line 2
>> this is line 3"
PS H:\>
PS H:\> $str
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
PS H:\>
PS H:\> & {$str
>> $str
>> $str}
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
PS H:\> history

  Id CommandLine
  -- -----------
   1 $str = "this is line 1...
   2 $str
   3 & {$str...


PS H:\>
```